# Node.js cannot read property 'item' of undefined

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, body-parser

I was doing The Net Ninja's Making a To-do App tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgAH0NqsJso&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gcy9lrvMJ75z9maRw4byYp&index=33). I am able to delete pre-defined items on the To-do-App but I am unable add items. Everytime I try to add an item, I get the error below. It seems there's something to do with the todos[i].item being undefined. Thanks for your time! Below is the .ejs file that contains the To-do-App.

```
TypeError: C:\Users\dlma1\Desktop\Nodejs Practice\znode-js-playlist\views\todo.ejs:17
    15|       <ul>

    16|         <% for(let i=0;i<todos.length;i++){ %>

 >> 17|           <li><%= todos[i].item %></li>

    18|         <% } %>

    19|       </ul>

    20|     </div>


Cannot read property 'item' of undefined
```

**Edit:
So there were quite a few files and I didn't want to overwhelm people so I'm going to post my github below. Apologies about not including the files earlier! I wasn't sure if the console error log was enough to diagnose the issue.

Comment: `todos[i]` is undefined, and therefore doesn't have an `item` key. what exactly is `todos`?

Comment: Sorry! I included it in a github repo now. It has a bunch of files so I couldn't fit it into the post without it looking really long when I was editing my post. Thanks for your help!

Comment: `data.push(res.body);` what is res.body? if you're pushing undefined into `data`, that'd explain the error.

Comment: Ohhh wow omg you're totally right =.= I've been trying to figure this out the entire day and it only took you like a minute how the heck. Thanks so much! It was supposed to be data.push(req.body);

Answer (score 0):

Must change data.push(res.body); to data.push(req.body);

Answer (score -1):

Could you share your whole code?
It seems hat when you add something to `todo` array its not being set properly, i.e your object assignment might be wrong or the input is `undefined`

Comment: Ah sorry about that! I uploaded the files onto my github since there's a lot of them. Thanks for having looked at my post! :)